# How to checkout a file version with unresolved conflicts?

Tags: git

While resolving merge conflicts I modified a file in favor of one version, but after some thought it looks like I want to get back some deleted lines. In other words I want to restore file version with unresolved conflicts, where I can again choose what to leave or what to delete.

I have modified other files too, so I don't want to go through some stashing and redoing the merge. Is it possible to do for one file?

Comment: `git checkout -m path/to/file`

Comment: This worked, it's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in @PetSerAI comment is correct and working:

```
git checkout -m path/to/file
```

Where `path/to/file` is your terminal / console relative path to file.

From `git checkout` documentation:

> The index may contain unmerged entries because of a previous failed
>   merge. By default, if you try to check out such an entry from the
>   index, the checkout operation will fail and nothing will be checked
>   out. Using `-f` will ignore these unmerged entries. The contents from a
>   specific side of the merge can be checked out of the index by using
>   `--ours` or `--theirs`. **With `-m`, changes made to the working tree file can be discarded to re-create the original conflicted merge result**.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

P.S. I assume nobody is posting an answer so I thought this would look better as an answer rather than comment.